# can not insert content to mysql database when use tinymce

Tags: php, mysql, tinymce-4

i try to use tinymce to my form with code like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>test</title>
<link href="admin.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
  selector: "#isi",
  plugins: [
    "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
    "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
    "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste"
],
 toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft  aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image"
});

 </script>
</head>
```

and my form code like this

```
<form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" id="form1" name="form1" method="POST">
<p>
  <label for="judul"></label>
  <label for="idkategory"></label >
  <select name="idkategory" class="login" id="idkategory" title="<?php echo $_SESSION['MM_UserName']; ?>"  required="required" >
    <option value="">Pilih Jenis Informasi</option>
     <?php
       do {  
     ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row_kategori['idkategory']?>"><?php echo $row_kategori['nama']?></option>
     <?php
          } while ($row_kategori = mysql_fetch_assoc($kategori));
          $rows = mysql_num_rows($kategori);
          if($rows > 0) {
          mysql_data_seek($kategori, 0);
         $row_kategori = mysql_fetch_assoc($kategori);
    }
   ?>
  </select>
  <input name="username" type="hidden" id="username" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['MM_Username']; ?>" />
</p>
<p>
  Judul <br /><textarea name="judul" id="judul" cols="55" rows="2" required="required"></textarea>
</p>
<p>
 Pengantar <br />
  <textarea name="pengantar" id="pengantar" cols="55" rows="3" required="required"></textarea>
</p>
<p>
 Isi <br />
  <textarea name="isi" id="isi" cols="55" rows="9" required="required"></textarea>
  <input name="foto" type="hidden" id="foto" value="no-image.png" />
</p>
<p>
  Tanggal <br />
   <?php

     $today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");                           // 20010310

   ?>
    <input name="tgl" type="text" required="required" id="tgl" value="<?php echo $today; ?>" size="30" />
    </p>
    <p>
     <input name="button2" type="reset" class="login" id="button2" value="Batal" />
    <input name="button" type="submit" class="login" id="button" value="Tambah Informasi" />
   </p>
   <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="form1" />
   </form>
```

my sql query is like this

```
  if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form1")) {

  $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO content (username, idkategory, judul,  pengantar, isi, foto, tgl) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['username'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['idkategory'], "int"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['judul'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['pengantar'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['isi'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['foto'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['tgl'], "date"));

  mysql_select_db($database_konek, $konek);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $konek) or die(mysql_error());

  $insertGoTo = "informasi.php";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
  $insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
 }
  header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));
}
```

when i click the submit button "Tambah Informasi", i can't save the content to databse mysql, the page not even blink. When i try to delete my tinymce script from the page, everthing is works well. Is there some thing wrong with my code? any help?

Comment: Try right clicking on the page and then click inspect element.  Then go to the console tab on the bottom of your screen.  After you have selected the console tab hit F5 to refresh the screen and see if you get any errors when the page loads.  You should also observe if there are any errors by hitting the submit button and see if any thing shows up in the console. Also I am assuming you have set the form action attribute variable earlier in your code somewhere?

Comment: @LarryLane, thanks for your help, I follow your intruction and  when i hit the submit button   i get this error `An invalid form control with name='isi' is not focusable.`, What thats mean?

Comment: It means that your required field named isi is not being filled.

Comment: Also it may be because tinymce is hiding the textarea because normally you would receive a message if a required form control is not filled.  Try removing the required from the isi textarea and see what happens?

Comment: @LarryLane,thanks i solve my problem with delete the required property from isi text area,the problem now is i need the required property, is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be because tinymce is hiding the textarea because normally you would receive a message if a required form control is not filled. Try removing the required from the isi textarea and see what happens?

If you still have to have to make sure the textarea is filled then you can use JavaScript to check to see if a value is present before submitting the form. It appears as if you have loaded Jquery so I will use that for my example.

JQuery:

```
//on submit function for form1
$("#form1".on("sumbit",function(event){//begin event

  //if the length of the isi textarea value is equal to 0
  if($("#isi")val().length === 0){//begin if then

   //stop the form from submitting
   event.preventDefault();

      //Do something else here like alert an error or make the text area a
      //different color

  }//end if then


});//end event
```

Answer (score 0):

Trim the value before insert. By default tinymce takes new line break.

Use trim:

```
trim($_POST['isi']);
```

or change in plugins

```
force_br_newlines : true,
force_p_newlines : false,
gecko_spellcheck : true,
remove_linebreaks : false,
```

Comment: What exactly error you get print  $insertSQL and run in phpmyadmin you will get exact error